# file not found error while upgrading to 17.10

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 17.10, facebook

I am upgrading from 16.04 to 17.10 but the installation aborts looking for `account-plugin-facebook_0.13+17.04.20170314-0ubuntu1_all.deb` package.

Comment: did you do `sudo apt-get update` to get the latest package lists before you tried upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

The package `account-plugin-facebook` was dropped from the Ubuntu repositories after 17.04. It [does not exist in 17.10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/account-plugins).

Uninstall the package before trying to upgrade to 17.10 or newer releases of Ubuntu.